# How to get ResponseType<?> from openapi 3

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator, raml

We are currently migrating some old rest interfaces from RAML to OpenAPI 3.
In the RAML file an HTTP delete operation has the response defined with empty body as follows:

```
delete:
  responses:
    204:
```

This generates java-code with a delete method with response type `ResponseEntity<?>`.
Generating with OpenAPI the same method with response type `ResponseEntity<Void>` is generated.
 
We don't want to change the implementation of the interface, so is there a way to generate a `ResponseEntity` with wildcard generic type from OpenAPI(3)?

Comment: How is the response currently defined in your OpenAPI file? What code generator do you use - Swagger Codegen, openapi-generator or something else? If you use Swagger Codegen or openapi-generator, what server/client do you generate (e.g.  `java` client or `jaxrs-jersey` server or similar)?

Comment: We don't have a response body defined, the response described above is the whole response. In the original raml it is defined the same way. We are using openapi-generator-maven-plugin 3.3.0 for generating a java interface annotated as Api.